# How to design a model to store dynamic field ResponseBody

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

When specifying a certain period, we prepare a Web API that returns data for each date in that period.

Specifically, POST

```
{"targetFrom": "2016-04-01", "targetTo": "2016-04-03"}}
```

The following JSON data is returned.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "StartTime": "2017-06-01T06:50:28.001344102Z", 
        "execute_time": 7532.0517, 
        "host": "----", 
        "rid": ""
    }, 
    "result": {
        "2016-04-01": {
            "0:num": 121, 
            "0:price": 5244614, 
            "1:num": 124, 
            "1:price": 6324547, 
            "2:num": 115, 
            "2:price": 5604491
        }, 
        "2016-04-02": {
            "0:num": 125, 
            "0:price": 6321222, 
            "1:num": 117, 
            "1:price": 5835030, 
            "2:num": 118, 
            "2:price": 5771826
        }, 
        "2016-04-03": {
            "0:num": 118, 
            "0:price": 5486071, 
            "1:num": 131, 
            "1:price": 6563447, 
            "2:num": 111, 
            "2:price": 5740078
        }, 
        "subTotal": {
            "total_2016-04-01_num": 360, 
            "total_2016-04-01_price": 17173652, 
            "total_2016-04-02_num": 360, 
            "total_2016-04-02_price": 17928078, 
            "total_2016-04-03_num": 360, 
            "total_2016-04-03_price": 17789596
            }, 
        "total": {
            "num": 1080, 
            "price": 52891326
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the part of the date field like "2016-04-01".
I would like to accept this on the application side of SpringBoot, consider processing modifications, and want to define an appropriate model.
However, I can not find a good method.

First of all, I considered the following as the foolish way.

```
@JsonProperty("2016-04-01")
private ResAnalyzeResultDayDto result_20160401;
```

This is stupid because it can not correspond to returned data that depends on the parameter targetFrom or targetTo at the time of inquiry.

So, how can we define a model to handle Response data with Field that dynamically changes according to request?
If you have a good idea, please let me know.

Additional notes:
I did not get along well as I wrote the following code.

```
@JsonProperty("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}")
private Map<String,ResAnalyzeResultSubTotalDayDto> maps;
```

In the first place, "@ JsonProperty" seems not to be able to use regular expressions, and I do not think that it will automatically set the key of map.

The code of the request part uses "RestTemplate".

```
ReqTotalSalesStatusDto reqGoMonth = new ReqTotalSalesStatusDto();
reqGoMonth.setStrTo("2016-04-03");
reqGoMonth.setStrFrom("2016-04-01");

// Jackson2HttpMessage
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

ResponseEntity<ResAnalyzeDto> resultGoMonth = restTemplate.exchange(
    "http://localhost:18000/analyze"
    , HttpMethod.POST
    , new HttpEntity<>(reqGoMonth)
    , ResAnalyzeDto.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take all result field to a map object like that:

```
private Map<String,Object> result;
result.forEach((k,v)->{
System.out.println("key: " + k + " value: " + v);
if("total".equals(k)){
    Total total = (Total) v;
} else if("subTotal".equals(k)) {
    SubTotal subTotal = (SubTotal) v;
} else {
    ResAnalyzeResultDayDto resAnalyzeResultDayDto = (ResAnalyzeResultDayDto) v;
}
});
```

After that you can check for keys. As for your example maps value can be 3 different objects. Total, SubTotal or DayInfo(ResAnalyzeResultDayDto). You can easily understand for total and subtotal and can cast them to corresponding object types. And for the rest of map's value they will be cast to ResAnalyzeResultDayDto.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, barbakini

I tried it in the way I taught, but I can not take it well at the cast, it is now one step. .

The log is as follows

```
key: 2016-04-01 value: {0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}
v.toString(): {0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}
2017-06-02 17:12:49.962 [maekawa-PC-http-nio-9999-exec-3]   ACS   XXX:[id: tenant_id:] url:/api/v1/totalsalesstatus/common3 status:200 elapsedNanoTime:8455258
2017-06-02 17:12:49.963 [maekawa-PC-http-nio-9999-exec-3]   ERROR  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to jp.co.temp.sample.management.report.api.dto.ResAnalyzeResultDayDto] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to jp.co.temp.sample.management.report.api.dto.ResAnalyzeResultDayDto
    at jp.co.temp.sample.management.report.api.TotalSalesStatusCommandService.lambda$createFinalResultObj3$3(TotalSalesStatusCommandService.java:609)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at jp.co.temp.sample.management.report.api.TotalSalesStatusCommandService.createFinalResultObj3(TotalSalesStatusCommandService.java:600)
```

Comment: Hi, Can You share ResAnalyzeResultDayDto class and the code fragment where you do casting? The reason is probably variables names does not match(Java does not allow variable names with ':' such as 2:num)

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
@Data
public class ResAnalyzeResultDayDto  {

@JsonProperty("0:num")
private int num0;

@JsonProperty("0:price")
private int price0;

@JsonProperty("1:num")
private int num1;

@JsonProperty("1:price")
private int price1;

@JsonProperty("2:num")
private int num2;

@JsonProperty("2:price")
private int price2;
}
```

code

```
private ResponseEntity<TotalSalesStatus> createFinalResultObj3(TotalSalesStatus resultObj,
        List<ResponseEntity<ResAnalyzeDto3>> goResponseEntityList ,String disposalDate) {

    String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
    this.logger.info("■■UT:[{}] ", methodName);

    int sumTotalNum = 0;
    int sumTotalPrice = 0;

    TotalSalesStatusGrandson totalSalesStatusDay = new TotalSalesStatusGrandson();
    resultObj.setTotalSalesStatusDay(totalSalesStatusDay);

    TotalSalesStatusGrandson totalSalesStatusMonth = new TotalSalesStatusGrandson();
    resultObj.setTotalSalesStatusMonth(totalSalesStatusMonth);

    boolean targetMonthFlag = false;
    for(ResponseEntity<ResAnalyzeDto3> e : goResponseEntityList){
        ResAnalyzeDto3 dto = e.getBody();
        ResAnalyzeMetaDto meta = dto.getMeta();
        Map<String,Map<String,?>> resu = dto.getResult();
        this.logger.info("■■UT:[{}] ResAnalyzeMetaDto  :{}", methodName,meta.toString());
        this.logger.info("■■UT:[{}] ResAnalyzeResultDto:{}", methodName,resu.toString());
            resu.forEach((k,v)->{
                System.out.println("key: " + k + " value: " + v);
                System.out.println("v.toString(): " + v.toString());
                String val = v.toString();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                if("total".equals(k)){
//                        ResAnalyzeResultTotalDto total = (ResAnalyzeResultTotalDto) v;
                    try {
                        ResAnalyzeResultTotalDto total = mapper.readValue(val,ResAnalyzeResultTotalDto.class);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if("subTotal".equals(k)) {
//                        ResAnalyzeResultSubTotalDto subTotal = (ResAnalyzeResultSubTotalDto) v;
                    try {
                        ResAnalyzeResultSubTotalDto subTotal = mapper.readValue(val,ResAnalyzeResultSubTotalDto.class);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
//                        ResAnalyzeResultDayDto resAnalyzeResultDayDto = (ResAnalyzeResultDayDto) v;
                    try {
                        ResAnalyzeResultDayDto resAnalyzeResultDayDto = mapper.readValue(val,ResAnalyzeResultDayDto.class);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    TotalSalesStatusGrandson totalSalesStatusYear = new TotalSalesStatusGrandson();
    totalSalesStatusYear.setTotal(new BigDecimal(sumTotalPrice));
    resultObj.setTotalSalesStatusYear(totalSalesStatusYear);
    resultObj.setUnitLabel("sample");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    ResponseEntity<TotalSalesStatus> result = new ResponseEntity<TotalSalesStatus>(resultObj, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    return result;
}
```

log

```
2017-06-05 13:33:48.382 [maekawa-PC-http-nio-9999-exec-1]   INFO  SAMPLE:[id: tenant_id:] j.c.b.b.m.r.a.TotalSalesStatusCommandService ■■UT:[createFinalResultObj3]
2017-06-05 13:33:48.382 [maekawa-PC-http-nio-9999-exec-1]   INFO  SAMPLE:[id: tenant_id:] j.c.b.b.m.r.a.TotalSalesStatusCommandService ■■UT:[createFinalResultObj3] ResAnalyzeMetaDto  :ResAnalyzeMetaDto(startTime=2017-06-05T04:33:48.499791734Z, executeTime=2.1928, host=bb8bfd9acf04, rid=)
2017-06-05 13:33:48.382 [maekawa-PC-http-nio-9999-exec-1]   INFO  SAMPLE:[id: tenant_id:] j.c.b.b.m.r.a.TotalSalesStatusCommandService ■■UT:[createFinalResultObj3] ResAnalyzeResultDto:{2016-04-01={0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}, 2016-04-02={0:num=125, 0:price=6321222, 1:num=117, 1:price=5835030, 2:num=118, 2:price=5771826}, 2016-04-03={0:num=118, 0:price=5486071, 1:num=131, 1:price=6563447, 2:num=111, 2:price=5740078}, subTotal={total_2016-04-01_num=360, total_2016-04-01_price=17173652, total_2016-04-02_num=360, total_2016-04-02_price=17928078, total_2016-04-03_num=360, total_2016-04-03_price=17789596}, total={num=1080, price=52891326}}
key: 2016-04-01 value: {0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}
v.toString(): {0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('0' (code 48)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: {0:num=121, 0:price=5244614, 1:num=124, 1:price=6324547, 2:num=115, 2:price=5604491}; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1771)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:684)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
    at jp.co.temp.sample.management.report.api.TotalSalesStatusCommandService.lambda$createFinalResultObj3$3(TotalSalesStatusCommandService.java:636)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
```